# Checking whether the group is empty SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

In OnConnected method client is added to the group with his name (group contains all of the client id) then his name is added to the list if it is not exists.

```
static List<string> onlineClients = new List<string>(); // list of clients names

public override Task OnConnected()
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);

    if (!onlineClients.Exists(x => x == Context.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        onlineClients.Add(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

In OnDisconnected method I'm trying to test whether the group is empty to remove element from list. But after removing last connection the group is not null.

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    if (stopCalled)
    {
        // We know that Stop() was called on the client,
        // and the connection shut down gracefully.

        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);

        if (Clients.Group(Context.User.Identity.Name) == null)
        {
            onlineClients.Remove(Context.User.Identity.Name);
        }

    }
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

Can I check for empty group?

Comment: question is not clear, what is `Groups` type ?

Comment: SignalR does not provide any APIs to query whether or not a group has any active clients. There is nothing stopping you from tracking this manually in OnConencted and OnDisconnected though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a little late reply to your question, maybe you've already forgotten :d

I solved the my problem as follows using a dictionary that holds group name(User.Identity.Name) and its client numbers.

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> onlineClientCounts  = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var IdentityName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, IdentityName);

    int count = 0;
    if (onlineClientCounts.TryGetValue(IdentityName, out count))
        onlineClientCounts[IdentityName] = count + 1;//increment client number
    else
        onlineClientCounts.Add(IdentityName, 1);// add group and set its client number to 1

    return base.OnConnected();  
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    var IdentityName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, IdentityName);

    int count = 0;
    if (onlineClientCounts.TryGetValue(IdentityName, out count))
    {
        if (count == 1)//if group contains only 1client
            onlineClientCounts.Remove(IdentityName);
        else
            onlineClientCounts[IdentityName] = count - 1;
    }

    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

Comment: This will work in a single server scenario, but will not scale